# Search by image / online reverse image search with Python | Check how widespread an image is

Tags: python, image, google-image-search

I am looking for a way to make a reverse image search with Python. So the input would be an image or an image-url and as an output I would like to have the number how often this image was found in the www and maybe the urls to these found images.

Is there an API I can use? Bing, Yahoo, Google? As far as I understand it is not possible with via Google… or is there a possible workaround?

In general I am interested in "measering" how spread or distributed an image is. If anyone has a suggestion please tell me :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this as possible (or very easy).

For a reverse image search, you would have to scan the entire internet, loading each page then checking if the image is there.

Personally, I would look into BeautifulSoup to read in the HTML data from googles own reverse image search (or some page that implements googles reverse image search)

Comment: Yes I also think this is not possible… but I thought maybe there is an API for such a service… but maybe there is not. 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you can't find an API for reverse image search, then probably the best route would be BeautifulSoup (handy module to have for getting any kind of information from html pages, VERY powerful.). I would think you could potentially parse google's own reverse search webpage given that you know basic HTML and reading up a bit on the BeautifulSoup documentation.